# Apollo query within NextJS's getServerSideProps?

Tags: next.js, apollo

I'm using NextJS with Apollo. The docs don't say much but point to this repo: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-apollo

Which uses this code:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const apolloClient = initializeApollo()

  await apolloClient.query({
    query: ALL_POSTS_QUERY,
    variables: allPostsQueryVars,
  })

  return {
    props: {
      initialApolloState: apolloClient.cache.extract(),
    },
    unstable_revalidate: 1,
  }
}
```

I find that quite ugly so I tried using a hook:

```
const res = useQuery(ALL_POSTS_QUERY);
```

But I get an error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

So can you not use hooks inside `getStaticProps` and `getServerSideProps`? If so is there a nicer syntax for making GraphQL queries?

Comment: There is this library but it mentions getInitialProps which isnt the current way of getting data in Next 9 https://github.com/lfades/next-with-apollo

Comment: No, as the error message says, hooks are for function components only. They give function components a persistent state as class components have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GraphQL Code Generator to make this nicer.

For example, I'm doing something similar and my code looks like this:

```
const response = await apolloClient.query<ViewerQuery>({
  query: ViewerDocument,
});
```

where `ViewerQuery` and `ViewerDocument` are generated by GraphQL Code Generator.

Comment: Hi!  I am using the same code in getServerSideProps, can you give me some advice?  Is it okay to initialize apollo on every page to send a request? My goal is to check existing dynamic routes

Comment: I'm not sure how lightweight it is to create a new apollo client. I assume it's not too bad, creating a new object should be negligible compared to fetching data, doing SSR, etc. You can measure it if you're worried. One thing to watch out for is that your apollo client on the server and client (browser) will have different caches, which may lead to some inconsistent results after mutating data.

Comment: Thanks for @arcticmatt's answer! Can you help me with my problem. I can create another stackoverflow question if needed. I'm trying to force a 404 status code for my dynamic routes, but the apollo client initialization on each page takes some delay, and I lose the main apollo trick - caching. At the moment I am checking the existing routes inside getServerSideProps. If I check it in the apollo hook it returns 202 instead of 404 status code. Thanks so much!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63877962/dynamic-routes-nextjs-with-status-code-404
This question is similar to my problem