# Dynamic routes nextjs with status code 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql, next.js

I have a project with dynamic route like **/[category]/[product]**. After a client-side request via useRouter to graphql for example **/hatchback/nissan/** returns a product with a code of 200, but if I make a request to **/hatchback/nissan111/**, I get an error because no such route exists and its response code still of 200 instead of 404. How can I check if a route exists and return a 404 status code during the component mount stage? I use SSR to achive this

Comment: Hi! Did you solve the problem? I have the same here but I am using apollo client in getServerSideProps